# Not connecting to database through java

Tags: java, html, postgresql-9.4

Actually I am trying to insert values from java servlet to postgres DB but they are not inserting.
Thanks in advance.

My html page is

```
<div class="container4">
          <h2>Registration form</h2>
          <form action="Register" method="get" >
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter firstname" name="firstname">
            </div><br><br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Username">Username:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username" name="username">
            </div><br><br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
            </div><br><br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
            </div><br><br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="address">Address:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Enter address" name="address">
            </div><br><br>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
```

My dbconnection page is

```
package dbConnection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
 * @author java2
 */
public class Dbconn {

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/classes","postgres", "admin123$");
            System.out.println("db successfull");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("db not successfull");
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

Register.java

```
package register;

import dbConnection.Dbconn;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    public class Register extends HttpServlet {  
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
                throws ServletException, IOException {  

    response.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;

    String n=request.getParameter("firstname");  
    String p=request.getParameter("username");  
    String e=request.getParameter("email");  
    String c=request.getParameter("pwd");
    String d=request.getParameter("address");



    try {


        con = Dbconn.getConnection();
        st = con.createStatement();

        int i = st.executeUpdate( 
    "insert into register (firstname, username, email, pwd, address) values('"+n+"','"+p+"','"+e+"','"+c+"','"+d+"')");
        con.commit();

        System.out.println("hello successfull");


       if (i == 0) {

            response.sendRedirect("login.html?msg=success");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("register.html?msg=failed");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }}
```

When I run this program I am getting like

**http://localhost:8088/trial/Register?firstname=jack&username=jack&email=jack%40gmail.com&pwd=jack&address=hyd**

I am getting all the details in url and displays blank page without errors. I am not understanding where I went wrong.

Comment: did you checked server console ? Since, you are using `System.out.println`

Comment: Ya when I run db.java separetly I am getting Sysout messages in console but when I run in web application then I am not getting any Sysouts in console.

Comment: post your web.xml. Also, post server console after `Submit`. Also, try changing `System.out` to `out`

Comment: Thank you friends but I came to know where I went wrong I gave form field names wrong in insert statement. I gave them based on form id but we should give based on database form field names.Now I am gettin my output